# Check class of child element using Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to check child element's class:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, } from "enzyme";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

function Bar() {
  return <div className="Bar" />;
}

function Component() {
  return (
    <div className="root">
      <Bar />
    </div>
  );
}

describe("foo", () => {
  it("should", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
    console.log(wrapper.hasClass("root"));
    console.log(
      wrapper
        .children()
        .first()
        .hasClass("Bar")
    );
  });
});
```

it prints `true` and `false`. why does the second `hasClass` returns `false`?

#### Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lyr53yjw7z)

#### UPD:

The fact that `.html()` returns all elements was misleading, I thought `shallow` actually renders everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
 wrapper
    .childAt(0)
    .dive()
    .hasClass("Bar")
```

If you `mount` your component you have to render it first for this to work:

```
    const w = mount(<Component />).render();
    expect(w.hasClass("root")).toBeTruthy();
    expect(
      w
        .children()
        .first()
        .hasClass("Bar")
    ).toBeTruthy();
```